# ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: bibtex

I suddenly got this error. I was compiling just fine before, everything worked, then suddenly bibtex provides me this error? I added another entry to the library unrelated to the one which provides the error, and it's the exact same format as all my other entries(C/P'ed from google scholar). What's up with this?

I attempted to comment out the citation which gave the error. Now it just moves the error around to other lines?

Tried deleting the .aux file associated with the .tex file, no dice.

Wait, i'm provided the following error: `arning--to sort, need author or key in forbes2012 Warning--empty year in forbes2012 Warning--empty journal in banea2008bootstrapping Warning--empty journal in fisher2011social (There was 1 error message)` - but, these are all entered with authopr and key? Empty year quite frankly isn't true, there is `year={20xx}` in all of them? Why?

Comment: The most common cause of this error is that you have a bib entry with no year. The warnings that says `empty year` in `forbes2012` is the relevant one. Are you sure that entry is well formed? Test it by making a document that cites *only* that item and nothing else, and post that here.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the forbes entry was wrong I think. What is the proper way to set up an article using natbib? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean an article `.bib` entry? Typically you should have at least author, year, journal and title present in the entry.  How are you managing your `.bib` file? If you use something like Jabref (cross platform) or BibDesk (Mac) the interface will typically catch some of these kinds or errors.

Comment: For the full safety, you should delete all auxiliary files (those that are generated automatically) but not only the `.aux` one. An auxiliary file might cause an error if the compilation is aborted while TeX is still writing it to the disk. It does not matter whether your last edit seems related to the error or not. And that is the reason that even you **Ctrl-Z** the file to the previous, compilable status, the error still pops up.